# How do I solve the following problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

Let's suppose I have the following function $f$:

$$f: \mathbb{R}^2\setminus (0,0) \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2y} - \frac{y}{2}$$

If I want to find the maxima and minima, the partial derivatives need to be calculated and be equal to zero. Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}= \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} = 0$$
$$ x^{-2} = -\frac{y^{-2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2} = 0 $$

So, what should I do now? Consider the following as maxima and minima? Should I call them as supremum and infimum? Should I change $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{\bar{R}}$?

Values:

$$\{(-\infty,-1),(-\infty,1),(\infty,-1),(\infty,1)\}$$

Obs.: If so, they are all maxima or minima according to the 2nd derivative test.

Thanks

Comment: Generally, in a standard vector calculus course, I would say that these are suprema and infima, not maxima and minima.

Comment: So that's the only difference between them? We allow suprema and infima be infinity while maxima and minima we do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method to observe that the given function is unbounded above and below is to note that
$$f\left(\dfrac1{n+1},1\right)=n\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N\\
f\left(4n,2n\right)=-n\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no $x$ such that $x^{-2}=0$.  Therefore there are no local maxima or minima.  Writing the single line with two equals signs may conceal this.

Comment: Yeah, sure. There is no such $x$ that satisfy this. But why couldn't we say that this is true when $x \to \infty$? It is not a maximum because it's usually a finite number, that's why we pick finite intervals. But when $x$ is arbitrarily big, wouldn't that be true?

Comment: When you ask for maxima and minima they are at points.  It can be useful to say that some terms go to zero as $x \to \infty$ but that does not answer the question as asked.  Given any point in the plane I can find a nearby point where the function value is higher and another where the function value is lower.  There are no local maxima or minima.  Globally we can use the $\frac 1x$ term to eliminate any proposed max/min.